# Rolling distinct count 30 day

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I need to turn this event tracker dataset from AWS Athena

```
timestamp      id     event
1577863551     1      home
1577863555     1      profile
1577863555     2      home
```

into Monthly Active User or unique user that active from 30-days ago till now. for example

```
date        MAU
2/1/2020    2000
2/2/2020    2500
```

2000 MAU means that from 1/3/2020 to 2/1/2020 there is 2000 unique user that active.
2500 MAU means that from 1/4/2020 to 2/2/2020 there is 2500 unique user that active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather complicated.  `count(distinct) over` would be *so much simpler*!  But here is the idea.

You want to get periods when a user is counted.  The idea is to generate a `user_inc` which is `1` when the user starts being counts and `-1` when it stops.

But this is not easy to count.  The idea is to add rows for when a user starts being counted and stopped being counted (by adding 31 days) -- with flags of `1` and -1` for these periods.  Then a cumulative sum determines if a user had activity on that date.  Filtering gets the first and last rows of periods with activity.

So, this looks like:

```
with t as (
      select id, dte, sum(sum(inc)) over (partition by id order by dte) as running_ins
      from ((select id, date(from_unixtime(timestamp)) as dte, 1 as inc
             from event_tracker
            ) union all
            (select id, date(from_unixtime(timestamp)) + interval '31' day as dte, -1 as inc
             from event_tracker
            )
           ) id
      group by id, dte
     ),
     first_last as (
      select id, dte, (case when running_ins > 0 then 1 else -1 end) as user_inc
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(running_ins) over (partition by id order by dte) as prev_running_ins
            from t
           ) t
      where prev_running_ins is null or
            prev_running_ins = 0 and running_ins > 0 or
            prev_running_ins > 0 and running_ins = 0
     )
select fl.dte,
       sum(sum(user_inc)) over (order by fl.dte) as distinct_30_days
from first_last fl
group by fl.dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1b63c473c8feab5e26fa79db15c5adbe) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres.

Comment: I have this problem: line 15:89: no viable alternative at input '(case when lag(running_ins) over (partition by user_id order by dte) as' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 55a759d7-c38c-425e-9da1-1f49b3b384aa)

Comment: @OctavianWR . . . There were multiple typos.  I fixed those and added a fiddle using Postgres to illustrate the idea.  Note:  Only dates that are in the original data (plus ate + 31 days) will be in the result set, so the sample results are not very interesting.

Comment: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 23:8: '"sum"("user_inc") OVER (ORDER BY "fl"."dte" ASC)' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

Comment: @OctavianWR . . . I miscopied the query from the fiddle.